# How to configure Laravel CORS to accept Nuxt 3 Proxy HTTP request?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cors, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to send a client request from `Nuxt 3` to an `api route` which leads to an `authentication controller` in laravel but it returns:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/authenticate' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

The request is sent by the Nuxt 3's `$fetch api`:

```
$fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/authenticate', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: form
    }).then((res) => {console.log(res)})
```

The request seems to be stopped before it can reach the `controller`. Here's `routes/api.php`:

```
// works
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return 'hello laravel';
});

// doesn't work, throws CORS error before request can reach Controller
Route::post('/authenticate', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'test']);

// works
Route::post('/authenticate', function () {
    return 'works';
});
```

Since `Laravel 9.2` there seems to be a `config/cors.php` file that can be configured but I don't know how. The default looks like this:

```
<?php

return [

    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,

];
```

Any idea how I could permit `api requests` to `auth routes` from Nuxt 3?

Comment: In my view, it may be better to proxy the API requests or the nuxt by Nginx instead of code, since it could be more common

Comment: You mean on the nuxt side? I was hoping to solve this on the laravel side because the nuxt 3 docs are not great yet and modules like `auth` are not implemented fully yet.

Comment: If you specify `'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie']` in your CORS configuration, how do you expect endpoints like `/test` and `/authenticate` (which do not match any of the specified paths) to be configured for CORS?

Comment: @jub0bs The routes you are referring to are in the `api.php` routes file. As you say, the `cors.php` are configures for all `/api/*` routes, which `/test` and `/authenticate` are part of.

Answer (score 0):

For laravel developers, it could be pretty easy to start an SSR Nuxt journey, especially when you write laravel with [Homestead](https://github.com/laravel/homestead)

Your SSR Nuxt site may use `example.com` as domain, also your Laravel API may called by prefix `http://example.com/api`(routes in the `routes/api.php`)

The Nginx config could be

```
    # before (Laravel default)
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;   
    }

    # after
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    location ~* ^/(api|broadcasting|storage)/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    location / {
        # the requests will be proxied to SSR Nuxt
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
```

In your SSR Nuxt3

```
$fetch('/api/authenticate', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: form
}).then((res) => {console.log(res)})
```

After that, you could save your days from handling CORS.

---

What's more about `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;`:

In SSR Nuxt, some requests are sent from front-end server, some requests are send from clients' browsers. When it comes from the front-end server, it could trigger the Laravel throttle with the IP of itself instead of the IP of client, to avoid this, you may add a `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;` first. Then add a request header for your Nuxt requests.

In SSR Nuxt2 (with @nuxtjs/axios), **plugins/axios.js**

```js
export default ({ $axios, store, req, error:nuxtError }) => {
    if (process.server) {
        $axios.setHeader('X-Forwarded-For', req.headers['x-forwarded-for']);
    }
}
```

In SSR Nuxt3, since there is an official HTTP client included, you don't need axios, view a [solution here](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/4504#discussioncomment-2659128)

Comment: Could this be done with the built-in `php dev server` instead of `nginx`?

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov You need something to proxy the requests